# Capture the size of textarea dynamically through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to trigger a event in jquery when the value of a textarea is changing without losing focus form textarea.

Comment: Where does 'size' come into your question? I'm confused by its presence in the title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`keyup` event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) to get the value as it's entered, like this:

```
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
  var newVal = $(this).val();
});
```

Or, to be a bit safer:

```
$("textarea").bind("keyup paste change", function() {
  var newVal = $(this).val();
});
```

Unlike *only* using `change` this will get the value as it updates, instead of when the `<textarea>` loses focus.

Comment: what does safer one do? does it associate three events concurently to textarea ?

Comment: @aniaz - yup, so when *any* of those happen your code runs...so you get the new value to update whatever you need ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/), although that's not *strictly* tied to the change of a value, just the events of a key being pressed.

```
$("textarea").keypress(
  function() {
     var newValue = $(this).val();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Autoresize with this jquery:
[JQUERY PLUGIN: ‘AUTORESIZE’](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)